# Programmatically change keyboard to Dvorak

Tags: windows, dvorak

Does anyone know the API call I can use to change the keyboard layout on a windows machine to Dvorak?  Doing it through the UI is easy but I'd like to have a script that I can run on new VM's to automate the process.

Comment: This sounds more like an April Fool's joke to me.

Comment: @David, no sadly a real question. I script everything I can manage and I'm a dvorak user :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I may be four years late to the party, but did you ever find this:

[Intlcfg Command-Line Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722068%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

I don't have Windows Vista (very bad habit, Windows), but looking at this page and also at [Available Language Packs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722435%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [Default Input Locales](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766503%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) I reckon the command you want might well be:

```
intlcfg.exe -inputlocale:0409:00010409
```

for English (United States) language with United States Dvorak input locale.

Comment: It may indeed be 4 years late but it's finally a correct answer :)

Answer (score 8):

You can do this via the registry.  Just save it as a .reg file, and open it on the new VM.  I believe this should do it for remapping to Dvorak:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"ScanCode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,22,00,00,00,2d,00,30,00,24,00,2e,00,\
11,00,33,00,33,00,11,00,12,00,20,00,34,00,12,00,1b,00,0d,00,0d,00,1b,00,16,\
00,21,00,17,00,22,00,20,00,23,00,1a,00,0c,00,2e,00,17,00,23,00,24,00,14,00,\
25,00,31,00,26,00,35,00,1a,00,30,00,31,00,13,00,18,00,26,00,19,00,2f,00,34,\
00,28,00,10,00,0c,00,28,00,19,00,13,00,18,00,1f,00,1f,00,27,00,2c,00,35,00,\
15,00,14,00,22,00,16,00,25,00,2f,00,10,00,2d,00,21,00,15,00,27,00,2c,00,00,\
00,00,00
```

And if you want to go back:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"ScanCode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: I looked at the registry on my machine (Vista) where I have Dvorak setup and I didn't see any of these entries.

Comment: Yes, probably selecting the layout in the UI sets some other flag.  This method will remap the keyboard, without changing the layout.  Its a strange distinction, but I think it explains the difference.

Comment: On XP: "Cannot import dvorak.reg: Not all data was successfully written to the registry.  Some keys are open by the system or other processes." I'm a university student so it would be nice if I could find a reliable way of quickly switching any PC I log in to to Dvorak, possibly by running a script in my user directory.