# Keyboard Type (Qwerty or Dvorak) detection

Tags: c#

I was asked this question by a friend, and it piqued my curiosity, and I've been unable to find a solution to it yet, so I'm hoping someone will know.

Is there any way to programatically detect what type of keyboard a user is using?  My understanding of the keyboard is that the signal sent to the computer for 'A' on a DVORAK keyboard is the same as the signal sent to the computer for an 'A' in a QUERTY keyboard.  However, I've read about ways to [switch to/from dvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167031/programatically-change-keyboard-to-dvorak), that highlight registry tweaking, but I'm hoping there is a machine setting or some other thing that I can query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you'd want to know? I can't think of one other than as a random statistic.

Comment: @Nathan: I'm not the questioner, but for a game you may map WASD to movement keys.  Works great in QWERTY, not so great in Dvorak.

Comment: I'm looking into writing a program for a tablet PC, and showing a virtual keyboard for quick input so that people don't have to unfold the box.  I'm trying to match the keyboard to the PC, and my friend noted that I might have to consider DVORAK vs QWERTY.  Thanks all for the responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by calling the GetKeyboardLayoutName() Win32 API method.
Dvorak keyboards have specific names. For example, the U.S. Dvorak layout has a name of 00010409.

Code snippet:

```
  public class Program
  {
    const int KL_NAMELENGTH = 9;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern long GetKeyboardLayoutName(
          System.Text.StringBuilder pwszKLID); 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder(KL_NAMELENGTH);

      GetKeyboardLayoutName(name);

      Console.WriteLine(name);

    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think I'll be able to handle foreign keyboards if I ever even start thinking about expanding into internationalizing my app.

Answer (score 3):

that probably depends on the OS. I'm sure that there is an operatingsystem setting somewhere that registers the nationality of the keyboard. (Dvorak is considered a nationality because French keyboards are different from US keyboards are different from ...)

Also, just a side note: 'A' was a bad example, as 'A' happens to be the same key in dvorak and qwerty... B-)

Comment: Not that I know of. Interesting question though.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do it via DirectInput, or whatever the current DirectX-equivalent is.  I type on a Dvorak keyboard, and about 50% of the games I buy detect my keyboard and reconfigure the default keymappings to support it (using ,aoe instead of wasd, for instance)

And yes, as Brian mentioned, 'A' is the same on both keyboards.

Comment: One other comment: Keyboards on Windows are distinct on a process-by-process basis.  You can have one window set to QWERTY and another set to an Arabic keyboard - as a matter of fact, in thirteen years of typing on a Dvorak, I have yet to find a way to globally change the keyboard layout.

Comment: Aric: YES! a fact that I find incredibly annoying!

Comment: I find that fact particularly useful. I do most of my low-keyboard intensive work (surfing the net, gaming) on QWERTY while I chat on Dvorak.

Comment: @aric The only solution I have found is to remove all other keyboard layouts/input languages from the system...

Answer (score 1):

Why would it matter? Depending on some special implementation of a keyboard is no good idea at all. We use barcode scanners all over the place that emulate keyboard inputs. What would your program do with these devices? :)

PS: the mentioned registry entry arranges the keys of a regular keyboard into dvorak layout.

Comment: How did you reach the assumption that he wanted to depend on key layout? It sounds more like he wants to support alternate key layouts. See Aric's answer for on of many good reasons why someone would do this.