# Detecting certain keys on an AZERTY keyboard?

Tags: c#, keyboard, keyboard-events, regional-settings, azerty-keyboard

I have an issue in a program where I am detecting key presses. All characters are working on QUERTY keyboards but I am aware of issues with certain characters on AZERTY keyboards.

For example, when \ is pressed on an AZERTY keyboard, it is given the keycode of 226 (â).

How can I ensure that the behaviour is consistent across keyboard layouts? I expected the inbuilt event handling to be consistent.

Comment: You might be able to check the key layout. I don't know the function. Question: does any one use google anymore?

Comment: show us how you are getting hold of the key presses

Comment: I am using the standard KeyDown event of the RichTextBox and checking e.KeyCode.

Comment: I have just noticed that the KeyPress event works as expected. However, I need to use the KeyDown event for my processing :(

Comment: For anyone still stumbling on this now, the answer of how to accurately get a character from a key code is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6929275/395685). I'm not gonna mark a decade old question as duplicate though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to first [detect the keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869609/keyboard-type-qwerty-or-dvorak-detection) and then use a different keycode to character mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce that at all. Backslash is composed on an AZERTY keyboard by holding down <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and then pressing the <kbd>8</kbd> key on the row of numbers above the letters. When you do that the following `KeyDown` events are fired:

- KeyCode: Menu, KeyValue: 18 for the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> going down
- KeyCode: D8, KeyValue: 56 for the <kbd>8</kbd> going down

On the other hand, if you press the key immediately to the left of <kbd>W</kbd> then a `KeyDown` with KeyCode OemBackslash and KeyValue 226 is fired, and a `<` character appears in the text box.

I wonder if your keyboard layout is not set correctly to match your particular keyboard. I'm assuming that your keyboard looks like the image on this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY

Answer (score 0):

Yes, different keyboard layouts give different key codes. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx) describes `VK_OEM_102` (keycode 226) as `"<>" or "\|" on RT 102-key keyboard`, so the keycode isn't even supposed to correspond to a single particular character.

To see which character a key corresponds to, use the [MapVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. You can then check whether it's a backslash.