# Change keyboard layout with python?

Tags: python, keyboard, registry

I'm working on a college system (windows XP) and want to set the keyboard to Dvorak when I log on. I currently have a python script that changes the desktop image.

Can I use python to change the layout as well? Or are there other ways?

Comment: One answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167031/programatically-change-keyboard-to-dvorak that doesn't programmatically change to the Dvorak layout but does remap all the keys -- that might be fine since registry settings will be cleared when you log out, assumably.

Comment: But how can you use vim with Dvorak? :/

Comment: I actually used vim with Dvorak for a while (back in aught-one).  Bit of a mind blower.  I got used to it, but I don't necessarily recommend it.

Comment: I didn't learn vim until well after converting to Dvorak, so vim with Dvorak works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

to Change keyboard layout

```
import win32api
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409',1) # to switch to english
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000401',1) # to switch to arabic
```

and for Dvorak :

```
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout("00010409",1)
```

or

```
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout("00020409",1)
```

Comment: Do you have the keyboard layout code for Dvorak or a link to the documentation for `win32api`?

Comment: use this to get your keyboard layout code: win32api.GetKeyboardLayout()

Comment: Thanks; but I don't want to find my own, I want to know whether `loadKeyboardLayout` has a Dvorak option, which is what OP is looking for.

Comment: I think the keyboard layout code for Dvorak is ("00010409" or "00020409")

Comment: I don't know - I asked because that was what the OP was asking for.  Thanks for adding it to the answer!

Comment: This doesn't really change current layout for me. Instead, it just adds new one to current list.

Answer (score 1):

answer can be found at [Programmatically change keyboard to Dvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167031/programatically-change-keyboard-to-dvorak)

Comment: comments are not supposed to be posted as answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to change the layout. You could write a script remapping the keys and compile it as an executable file.

For example

```
q::'
+q::"
w::,
+w::<
e::.
+e::>
r::p
```

etc.