# Automatically change keyboard language based on different fields

Tags: javascript, python, keyboard, persian

I have an application in which a user is presented two fields, one for typing English and second one for typing Arabic / Persian characters.

I want the keyboard input language to automatically change to Arabic/Pesian when the arabic/persian language field is focused.

The language for the development of the application is Python! Is there a Javascript library for doing this or any other scripts?

Comment: I don't know about Python, but it may be possible to use events to detect field changes/focus.

Comment: You should probably check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420925/change-keyboard-layout-with-python